# What data structure using O(n log n) storage with O(log n) query time should I use for Range Minimum Queries?

Tags: java

*Suppose that we are given a sequence of n values x1, x2 ... xn, and seek to quickly answer repeated queries of the form: given i and j, find the smallest value in xi... xj
Design a data structure that uses O(n log n) space and answers queries in O(log n) time.*

I know the solution of data structure with O(n) space and O(log n) time , but I need an answer
that uses O( n log n) space not less .

any suggestions ?

solution for O(n) space :

O(n) space : For input of a1,a2,a3,...an , construct a node that contains minimum of (a1,..,ak) and minimum of (ak+1,..,an) where k = n/2. Recursively construct the rest of the tree. Now, if you want to find the minimum between ai and aj: Identify the lowest common ancestor of i,j. Let it be k Start with i and keep moving until you hit k. AT every iteration check if the child node was left node. If yes, then compare the right subtree's min and update current min accordingly. Similarly, for j, check if it is right node.... At node k compare values returned by each subtree and return the min

Comment: If you want to waste some space; sure, why not?

Comment: Why do you want to have O(nlogn) when you have a better -O(n)- solution?

Comment: Note that any `O(n)` solution is also `O(n log n)` so your solution (if it works) is technically correct as is.

Comment: Instead I suggest you show us your solution and we show you the fault in it. If we fail to, I suggest you should be able to collect some great sum or awe from the leturer.

Comment: First make sure your notation is correct. Big-O and little-o have *very* different meaning in this context. You appear to be using them interchangeably.

Comment: thank you for attention , but I want to know how I can solve this problem without using the problem with O(n) memory . I guess the solution must have a different ineresting structure !

Comment: @JanDvorak: As far as educational value goes, I think it's slightly preferable for the OP to rework their question so that it makes sense. If you prefer to do it for them, I doubt anyone would object (I certainly wouldn't).

Comment: @elahe It seems to me that your algorithm actually works.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `O(n)` is also `O(n logn)`, so technically any solution that's `O(n)` is automatically also `O(n logn)`.

What you seem to be asking is a solution that uses `Θ(n logn)` memory (note the [theta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)). I have to say I think this is a slightly odd requirement given that you claim you already have a superior `Θ(n)` solution.

In any case, you can trivially transform your `Θ(n)` solution into a `Θ(n logn)` one by making `log(n)` copies of your data structure.

Comment: thank you for helping me, I know that O(n) is also O(n log n) ,  but I want to know how I can solve this problem without using the problem of O(n) memory . I guess the solution must have a different ineresting structure !